# What is the source of this latency?

Tags: debian, server, rust, vps, latency

I have a website written in Rust that you can find the source code [here](https://github.com/Ap0ph1s/Oxidized), The website is running on a 512mb RAM VPS in NYC hosted by DigitalOcean.

I have noticed, and have gotten complaints from beta testers, that sometimes the website takes a long time to load. I added timers to see which function of my code takes the longest, but every request is well below 0 milliseconds. I am timing the duration of the middleware component.

I tried using Pingdom.com and Real User Monitoring (RUM) to see if the requests take longer than they should. Some take more than 15s to load, HOWEVER, this latency problem is not consistent. Most of the time it's well below 0 seconds for load time.

When I observe those requests coming in using the developer console in Safari, I see that there's about 350 ms of latency on a request which takes 15 ms.

Comment: This sounds like a network latency issue, either on the client side or on digitalocean's datacenter. It's not abnormal for some package to get lost on the way, and then the whole request suffers from [HOL blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-of-line_blocking)

Comment: One simple way to know if the issue comes from Rust is to set static pages up and ask beta testers about latency again.

Comment: "Most of the time it's well below 0 seconds for load time" - I feel like if you are less than 0 load time, then you are probably doing something way better than everyone else on the Internet!

Comment: @Shepmaster Im getting this from Pingdom.com, also the webpages arent alot, nor are the Rust functions, Rust is pretty fast, as I believe you know :P

Comment: I assume you mean it is well below 1 second, since being below 0 (getting a response before it was requested) usually requires time travel.

Comment: Yes, below 1 second, I was kinda not really thinking about this

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

1. Your application is getting swapped to disk

   Meaning the OS thinks there are better things to have in RAM than your application. Usually happens if your app doesn't receive any request for say, hours. Probably not your problem.
2. Your upload is spiky or non-existent.

   Try downloading a large file from your server and watch the download speeds.
3. Your network has packet loss or high latency

   Test with running ping for few minutes. A good connection shouldn't have any loss and not much variation in latency. This one is probably the issue based on what you've said.
4. Your framework is slow

   I doubt this one. You can test yourself by building a test app to send lots of local requests and making sure latency stays low.
5. You have a bad neighbor

   Since you are using a VPS, who like to oversubscribe hosts, chances are you may have a bad neighbor. Another user who likes to use up the entire physical network connection to the host or a ton of CPU could hurt everyone. There may be several users doing this to bring a host to its knees.

For packet loss and high latency, you should complain to your provider and include tests that show the loss. VPS hosts are often oversold and the provider may not have proper monitoring of the host to re-balance load. Or they may not care until someone complains.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the number of threads that Iron defaults to, which was 2 in this case because of my 1 core VPS, so the latency was because 1 person was trying to connect to the website while the other connection was still open.